# spring @Transaction not rollingback with two tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

It involves insert operation in two tables in a single transaction. In case of exception
transaction is not rolling back. Transaction is initiated in the first transaction and the next dao call continues in the same session.  roll back on exception pattern is set, still it is not rollin back. can anyone please help
Pom Dependency:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
           <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>



      </dependencies>
```

Confiuration xml

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.dao.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.user.impl" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@org-e0a6b74ade3:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
        <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
    </bean>

  </beans>
```

Dao :

```
   @Repository
    public class AddressDaoImpl implements AddressDao{

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY ,
      rollbackFor={MyEx1.class,Exception.class,org.hibernate.HibernateException.class})
        public void insertAddress(Address address) {
            Session session  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            System.out.println("session>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>3*  "+    session.hashCode());
            session.save(address);
            session.flush();
        }

    }


    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, 
            rollbackFor={MyEx1.class,Exception.class,org.hibernate.HibernateException.class})
    public void insertUser(User user, Address address) throws MyEx1 {
    Session session  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println("session>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>2*  "+    session.hashCode());
    session.save(user);
    addressDao.insertAddress(address);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
    throw new MyEx1("User inserted!");
    //session.getTransaction().commit();
    //session.close();



    }
```

Comment: Don't close the session. That's Spring's job. Flushing it is unnecessary.

Comment: What is the code that calls these two methods? Does it start a transaction?

Comment: @user3314249 seems like somehow there are two separate transactions, one might be rolling back, but not the second one, post some more code, the calling methods etc.